# What does ~ do in scala?

Tags: scala, playframework

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Understanding the tilde in Scala’s parser combinators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6818390/understanding-the-tilde-in-scalas-parser-combinators)

I saw the following in this play2 [tutorial](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/ScalaTodoList):

```
  val task = {
    get[Long]("id") ~
    get[String]("label") map {
      case id~label => Task(id, label)
    }
  }
```

What does the `~` mean? (Searching for `~` in Google didn't return anything).
And why it seemed to be at the end of a line first and then it seems to connect two attributes?

Comment: Use [symbolhound](http://symbolhound.com/) for looking up things like this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Scala syntax allows method names to use special characters such as `+`, `*` and `:`, and to use them as infix operators, which effectively allows operator overloading as well as the creation of new operators. This can make code more concise, but can also make it difficult to figure out what a particular Scala operator does, because you can't effectively do a Google search for `\:` or `++` or `~` or `::` or pretty much any Scala operator method name. To make it even more difficult, an implicit conversion may be applied to one of the operands, so the class providing the operator method may not be the same as the declared class of the operand in the source code.

**UPDATE**: Use [**Scalex**](http://scalex.org/)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll check that page (But I have Ruby background, and I just felt that you were speaking to me in Chinese).

Comment: In what way its a bliss (besides performance)?

Comment: FYI, scalex.org is not for Scala anymore.

Answer (score 5):

Scalex, can do all those ascii and unicode character searches (also discusssed pretty well in Horstmann's "Impatient" book

http://scalex.org/?q=~

http://scalex.org/?q=%E2%8A%9B

http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/book-index.html#indexanchor

Answer (score 1):

It's a [combinatory parser](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/combinator-parsing.html)

[Live example](http://scala.masgui.cloudbees.net/50cca736e4b0a825d655e7d6)

This is a assignement I had in a compiler course at the university it simplify an algebraic expression

```
( x + 0 ) - ( 1 * --x )
x + - ( 1 * --x )
x + - ( --x )
x + - ( x )
0
```

Building a sql table is something similar

Th first part

```
get[Long]("id") ~
get[String]("label")
```

parse two rows

and the map case give you the parsed result

Take a look at [that](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/anorm/src/main/scala/anorm/SqlParser.scala#L106) and [that](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/anorm/src/main/scala/anorm/Anorm.scala)

I remember this is one of the first things I saw when I started learning scala/play. I suggest you take a good break and read the whole book ( [programming in scala 2nd edition](http://www.artima.com/shop/programming_in_scala_2ed) ) and do this [online class](https://www.coursera.org/course/progfun)

You should also consider lift