# What does the tilde (~) mean in this Scala example?

Tags: scala, anorm

http://woss.name/2012/04/02/retrieving-bigdecimals-from-a-database-with-anorm-scala/

```
object Site {
  val allFieldsParser = {
    get[Pk[Long]]("sites.id") ~     // Help me parse this syntax
    get[String]("sites.name") ~
    get[BigDecimal]("sites.latitude") ~
    get[BigDecimal]("sites.longitude") map {
      case id ~ name ~ latitude ~ longitude =>
        Site(id, name, latitude, longitude)
    }
  }

  def findAll(): Seq[Site] = {
    DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
      SQL("SELECT * FROM sites").as(Site.allFieldsParser *)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This notation was derived from parser combinators. Please, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6818390/understanding-the-tilde-in-scalas-parser-combinators In short, you may mentally replace `~` with `&`, so such structure will look like a pattern (you know, like a pattern in regex). You're defining high level representation using particular parts (combined into solid structure with ~'s) and then parser either succedes, and you got structure according your scheme, or fails. For example, to match algebraic expression one could write something like `Number ~ Operation ~ Number ...`

Comment: @om-nom-nom So, why did you answer in the comment?

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral because I'm unsure whether the question is about technical implementation (which was already explained by gzm0) or about semantical stuff.

Comment: Actually it's the operator symbol for tilda swinton.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In your example, ~ is being used in two different ways to mean two different things.  In the first part you have

```
get[Pk[Long]]("sites.id") ~     // Help me parse this syntax
get[String]("sites.name") ~
get[BigDecimal]("sites.latitude") ~
```

etc.  As it has already been pointed out, this is just method invocation, it is the same as

```
get[Pk[Long]]("sites.id").~(get[String]("sites.name").~(...
```

You can look at [the definition of this method in the anorm source](https://github.com/playframework/anorm/blob/d83589bbf9e532f1de6b1dd7006e972e0e85b4dc/core/src/main/scala/anorm/SqlParser.scala#L567).  It is a method on a `RowParser[A]` (a parser that parses an `A`, which takes a `RowParser[B]` (a parser that parses a `B`) and returns a parser that parses a `A ~ B`.  This `A ~ B` is a second meaning for `~`.  This is now referring not to a method, but to a [case class defined in the same file here.](https://github.com/playframework/anorm/blob/d83589bbf9e532f1de6b1dd7006e972e0e85b4dc/core/src/main/scala/anorm/SqlParser.scala#L507)

```
case class ~[+A, +B](_1: A, _2: B)
```

This is just a idiosyncratic way of referring to a class `~[A,B]`. At the *type level*, when you have a two argument type constructor, you can use the name of the class in infix notation.  This isn't anything special about `~`, it would work with any two argument type constructor.  If you had `trait Foo[A,B]` you could refer to that as `A Foo B`. Analogously, in *pattern matching*, variables `a` and `b` can be bound using the syntax `a Foo b`, which is referred to as an *Infix Operation Pattern* in section 8.1.10 of the [language specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf).

In the second part of your example you have:

```
case id ~ name ~ latitude ~ longitude =>
```

This is pattern matching on these `~` case clases which are the result of running the parse you constructed above.  So this is really just a nicer way of writing:

```
case ~(~(~(id, name), latitude), longitude) =>
```

Answer (score 6):

In Scala

```
a ~ b
```

means

```
a.~(b)
```

So it calls the method `~` on `a` and gives `b` as an argument. Also note that any operator not ending with `:` is left-associative.

Your example revisited would be:

```
get[Pk[Long]]("sites.id").~(     // Help me parse this syntax
get[String]("sites.name").~(
get[BigDecimal]("sites.latitude").~(
get[BigDecimal]("sites.longitude")))) map {
  case id ~ name ~ latitude ~ longitude =>
    Site(id, name, latitude, longitude)
}
```

Comment: More generally, `a whatever b` means `a.whatever(b)` (with the exception of some keywords, primitive operators, and the left-associative indicator you already mentioned).